# Can not view the tab contents

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react and I have two tabs under the two tabs I have few projects listed. now by default, my first tab is set and if I press another tab I can not see the contents.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Tabs,
  Tab,
  Grid,
  Cell,
  Card,
  CardTitle,
  CardText,
  CardActions,
  Button,
  CardMenu,
  IconButton
} from "react-mdl";

class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeTab: 0 };
  }

  toggleCategories() {
    if (this.state.activeTab === 0) {
      return (
        <div className="projects-grid">
          {/* 1st project*/}
          <Card shadow={5} style={{ mimWidth: "450", margin: "auto" }}>
            <CardTitle
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                height: "176px",
                background:
                  "url(https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/react-1.svg) center / cover"
              }}
            >
              React Project #1
            </CardTitle>
            <CardText>Personal Protfolio</CardText>
            <CardActions border>
              <Button colored>
                <a href="https://github.com/mjachowdhury/myPortfolio">Github</a>
              </Button>
              <Button colored>CodePen</Button>
              <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
            </CardActions>
            <CardMenu style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              <IconButton name="share" />
            </CardMenu>
          </Card>
      );
    }
```

Second Tab has contents to show projects

```
else if (this.state.activeTab === 1) {
      return (
        <div className="projects-grid">
          {/* 1st project*/}
          <Card shadow={5} style={{ mimWidth: "450", margin: "auto" }}>
            <CardTitle
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                height: "176px",
                background:
                  "url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ08kJ77S5fZJQDJyjs6rgSQqFszjq6tyt31ui_-QXbU4W3ZpQV&s) center / cover"
              }}
            >
              {/*Angular Project #1*/}
            </CardTitle>
            <CardText>Angular Project #1 - Exhivision Website</CardText>
            <CardActions border>
              <Button colored>
                <a href="https://github.com/mjachowdhury/myPortfolio">Github</a>
              </Button>
              <Button colored>CodePen</Button>
              <Button colored>Live Demo</Button>
            </CardActions>
            <CardMenu style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
              <IconButton name="share" />
            </CardMenu>
          </Card>
          {/* 2nd project*/}
          <Card shadow={5} style={{ mimWidth: "450", margin: "auto" }}>
            <CardTitle
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                height: "176px",
                background:
                  "url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ08kJ77S5fZJQDJyjs6rgSQqFszjq6tyt31ui_-QXbU4W3ZpQV&s) center / cover"
              }}
            > 
      );
    }
```

The render part has logic to show different tab contents.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="category-tabs">
        <Tabs
          activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
          onChage={tabId => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId })}
          ripple
        >
          <Tab>React</Tab>
          <Tab>Angular</Tab>
        </Tabs>

        <Grid>
          <Cell col={12}>
            <div className="content">{this.toggleCategories()}</div>
          </Cell>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

this is so far I have done and it not showing my second tab contents. Any idea

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code to reproduce the issue and created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-hertz-mchwq)

Unfortunately it won't be helpful. However if you open your console you will also see your mistake regarding the type you have made in the  section where you are calling the `onChange` method as `onChage`.

Comment: perfect its working what a type o but it didn't give me any error. thank you so much for noticing it.